# How can I keep on updating two different print statements?

Tags: python

How do I make it such I can update each print statement, without the one overwriting the other, or keep on creating new lines, nor clearing the window each time?

```py
print(f"\r[~] Progress: {index}/{len(ids)}", end='', flush=True)
print(f"\n[~] Total elapsed time: {minutes} minutes {seconds} seconds", end='', flush=True)
```

What I want is to keep updating, without the one overwriting the other in the terminal?

```
[~] Progress: 1/4
[~] Total elapsed time: 2 minutes 34 seconds
```

Comment: Feature you are asking depends on OS *and* Terminal in use. Typically something like this is done via "curses" module thats ships with python but only works with linux & mac.  There is however some wrappers that also provide compatible layer for curses to work on windows. Start here;  https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html

Comment: This would be much, much easier if all of the information being updated was on a *single line*.  You could produce that line with multiple `print`s if you really want to, there just cannot be a `\n` output anywhere as then you can't get back to the beginning with a `\r`.